# How to use generics with classes full of constants?

Tags: c#, generics

I hope it becomes clear what I mean. I have multiple static class full of options:

```
static class Thing1
{
    public const string Name = "Thing 1";
    // More const fields here.
}

static class Thing2
{
    public const string Name = "Thing 2";
    // More const fields here.
}
```

Now I want to use those options to create a class which includes the contents of one of these classes.

```
public void Create<T>()
{
    var foo = new Foo(T.Name);
    foo.Prop = T.Something;

    if (T.HasValue)
        foo.Add(T.Value);
}
```

But of course this doesn't work. I would use interfaces, but static classes can't implement interfaces.

Is there any way to make this work elegantly? Making `Thing1` and `Thing2` singletons would work, but that isn't a very nice solution.

I could create a struct and put the objects into another static class, but I was wondering whether you could do something like the above.

Comment: You can't use Generics and Static at the same time, it's one or the other.

Comment: @gunr2171 So there is no way of achieving this? That's a shame.

Comment: You can get it to work, just not by using Static. Can you give a more concrete example of _why_ you're doing this pattern?

Comment: @gunr2171 It's for a game, the static classes are the properties of entities and the `Create` function would create the actual game entities with the specified properties.

Comment: I mean for Generics, no, no way. You could still use Reflection though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can create an interface and make your classes non-static and inherit from this interface:

```
public class Thing1 : IThing
{
    public string Name { get; } = "Thing 1";
    // More const fields here.
}

public class Thing2 : IThing
{
    public string Name { get; } = "Thing 2";
    // More fields here.
}

interface IThing 
{   
    string Name { get; }
}
```

And then use it for your method together with type parameter constraint:

```
public void Create<T>(T t) where T : IThing
{
    // Now compiler knows that `T` has all properties from `IThing`
    var foo = new Foo(t.Name);
    foo.Prop = t.Something;

    if (t.HasValue)
        foo.Add(t.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try *Reflection*: scan assemblies for `static` classes, obtain `public const string` fields with their values from them and materialize them as a `Dictionary<T>`

```
  using System.Linq; 
  using System.Reflection;

  ...

  // Key   : type + field name, say Tuple.Create(typeof(Thing1), "Name")
  // Value : corresponding value, say "Thing 1";
  static Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string>, string> s_Dictionary = AppDomain
    .CurrentDomain
    .GetAssemblies() // I've taken all assemblies; you may want to add Where here
    .SelectMany(asm => asm.GetTypes())
    .Where(t => t.IsAbstract && t.IsSealed) // All static types, you may want to add Where
    .SelectMany(t => t
       .GetFields()                         // All constant string fields
       .Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(string))
       .Where(f => f.IsPublic && f.IsStatic)
       .Where(f => f.IsLiteral && !f.IsInitOnly) // constants only
       .Select(f => new { 
         key = Tuple.Create(t, f.Name),
         value = f.GetValue(null)
       }))
    .ToDictionary(item => item.key, item => item.value?.ToString());
```

If you want to scan not all loaded but just one (executing) assembly

```
  static Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string>, string> s_Dictionary = Assembly
    .GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsAbstract && t.IsSealed) 
    ...
```

Now you can wrap the dictionary, say

```
  public static string ReadConstant<T>(string name = null) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
      name = "Name";

    if (s_Dictionary.TryGetValue(Tuple.Create(typeof(T), name), out string value))
      return value;
    else
      return null; // Or throw exception
  }
```

Usage

```
 string name1 = ReadConstant<Thing1>();
```

Comment: I imagine this has a considerable runtime cost, right?

Comment: @Rakete1111: It runs just *once* (having the *dictionary* you can get the answer immediately); it may well appear, that we don't want to scan *all* the loaded assemblies as `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(asm => asm.GetTypes())...` but just *one*, say `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()...`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a static classes with constants.  You can create a class with properties and static instances with the desired values.

```
public class Thing
{
    private Thing(string name, string something, bool hasValue, string value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Something = something;
        HasValue = hasValue;
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public string Something{ get; }
    public bool HasValue { get; }
    public string Value{ get; }

    public static Thing Thing1 { get; } = new Thing("Thing1", "Something1", true, "Value1");
    public static Thing Thing2 { get; } = new Thing("Thing2", "Something2", false, null);
}
```

And then your method would just take that class.

```
public void Create(Thing t)
{
    var foo = new Foo(t.Name);
    foo.Prop = t.Something;

    if (t.HasValue)
        foo.Add(t.Value);
}
```

Then you'd call it with either

```
Create(Thing.Thing1);
```

or

```
Create(Thing.Thing2);
```

Comment: You might wanna add `readonly` to the static fields `Thing1` and `Thing2`.

Comment: A factory method would be nice to create the Thing object and initialized all properties. No. of constructor arguments might get ugly if Thing1 suppose to have more than 5 (code smell) properties to initialize.

Comment: @vendettamit its a bit ironic to talk about code smell and recommend a factory in the same comment

Comment: Sure! If you would like to share some insights.

Comment: @juharr Might I ask why you prefer `{ get; }` over `readonly` in this situation, just curious.

Comment: @Twenty Just a general preference for properties over exposing fields.

Answer (score 1):

You could use non static classes and add those to a dictionary having a `Type` key. But you would have to use read-only properties.

```
public interface IConstants
{
    string Name { get; }
    double InitialHealth { get; }
    public int? MaxTries { get; }
}

public class Thing1 : IConstants
{
    public string Name => "Thing 1";
    public double InitialHealth => 100.0;
    public int? MaxTries => null;
}

public class Thing2 : IConstants
{
    public string Name => "Thing 2";
    public double InitialHealth => 80.0;
    public int? MaxTries => 10;
}
```

Initialize the dictionary:

```
public static readonly Dictionary<Type, IConstants> Constants =
    new Dictionary<Type, IConstants> {
        [typeof(Thing1)] = new Thing1(),
        [typeof(Thing2)] = new Thing2(),
    };
```

The `Create` function:

```
public void Create<T>()
{
    Type key = typeof(T);
    var foo = new Foo(key.Name);
    IConstants constants = Constants[key];
    foo.InitialHealth = constants.InitialHealth;

    if (constants.MaxTries is int maxTries) { // Only true if MaxTries.HasValue.
                                                // Converts to int at the same time.
        foo.Add(maxTries);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some reflection I came up with another solution. Why select the constants by type? It is much easier if we use the same type to store the different sets of constants.

```
public class Constants
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Health { get; set; }
    public int? MaxTries { get; set; }
}
```

We then identify the sets through an `enum`:

```
public enum SetType
{
    Set1, // Please use speaking names in a real implementation!
    Set2,
    Set3
}
```

We define the values of the constants while creating the dictionary of constants sets:

```
public static readonly Dictionary<SetType, Constants> ConstantSets =
    new Dictionary<SetType, Constants> {
        [SetType.Set1] = new Constants { Name = "Set 1", Health = 100, MaxTries = null },
        [SetType.Set2] = new Constants { Name = "Set 2", Health = 80, MaxTries = 5 },
        ...
    };
```

The `Create` method becomes

```
public void Create(SetType set)
{
    var constants = ConstantSets[set];
    var foo = new Foo(constants.Name) {
        Health = constants.Health
    };
    if (constants.MaxTries is int maxTries) {
        foo.Add(maxTries);
    }
}
```

No generics, no reflection, no fancy stuff required.